# Does javac removes methods that are not referenced in the code?

Tags: java, javac

I have a code base and some methods are never used.
Does `javac` remove the unused methods from the class file?

Comment: Not if the methods are `public`, I should hope.

Comment: @larsmans: Why is it special for `public`? Is it because some other code might be using them? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: I want to know if I have a code base and some methods are never used. Does javac remove the unused methods from the class file?

A: No.  What goes into the class, stays in the class file.

... however ...

The JVM loads only what's needed into memory.  RAM isn't "wasted" on unused classes.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't. To verify this, you can run

```
javap -c foo.bar.MyClass
```

and see all the code there. You can also access it via reflection (assuming you're running with appropriate permissions).

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't and it can't. 
Think about what would happen if the compiler did that when you compile a library. All methods that the library wants to **export** for users, but doesn't use itself would be removed. 
And there is no way in Java to distinguish between something that is a library and your code.